# How to recover a pickled class and its instances

Tags: python, pickle

I would like to store a class and many instances for later use, or to give to someone else.

So far I can pickle and recover the instances, but I have to recreate the class by hand before loading them.

I've looked at [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) documentation which leads me to believe I should be able to do this somehow, but I can't seem to find out exactly how to do it.

EDIT: I've read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28095208/3904031) discussing the use of `dill`(see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26410499/3904031) answer also), but I don't have `dill` installed. I'd like a pickle solution if it exists.

```
import numpy as np
import pickle

class wow(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

w5 = wow(np.arange(5))
w3 = wow(range(3))

with open("w5w3.pickle", "w") as outfile:
    pickle.dump([w5, w3], outfile)

# save the class also
with open("wow.pickle", "w") as outfile:
    pickle.dump(wow, outfile)

# OK, now delete class wow, then try to recover the pickles
del wow, w3, w5

try:
    with open("wow.pickle", "r") as infile:
        wow = pickle.load(infile)

except Exception, e:  # returns: "'module' object has no attribute 'wow'"
    print str(e)
    print "so manually recreate class wow"

    class wow(object):
        def __init__(self, x):
            self.x = x  

with open("w5w3.pickle", "r") as infile:
    W = pickle.load(infile)

for thing in W:
    print type(thing.x), thing.x
```

Comment: have you tried pickling the class too? `pickle.dump([wow, w5, w3], outfile)`

Comment: yes pls see lines ~14-16. Also tried your way, no change.

Comment: i think you have to use 'wb' and 'rb' to binary writing and reading files

Comment: `dill` installs with `pip install`… and is pure python… so why don't you want to install it?  Of course, being the `dill` author I'm biased… but with `dill`, you have a simple solution to your problem.

Comment: I learned much more by asking this question and then understanding why specifically pickle will not pickle a class. There are also security issues with `dill` that I don't yet completely understand. Reflexively installing anything that some stranger tells you to install is not always wise. I think the best solution is the one in the accepted answer: send the class as readable python, and the objects in a pickle.

Comment: **NOTE:** the security issue(s) applies similarly to pickle and dill. Both might contain some naughty python (which you can't easily see afterward) as well as maliciously inserted instructions after pickling - see all three answers to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34314289/3904031)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the error is caused because you deleted the class definition. Object serialization in Python (which to my knowledge is also in Java) requires the class definition to be there.

From your linked documentation:

> Note that functions (built-in and user-defined) are pickled by “fully qualified” name reference, not by value. This means that only the function name is pickled, along with the name of the module the function is defined in. Neither the function’s code, nor any of its function attributes are pickled. Thus the defining module must be importable in the unpickling environment, and the module must contain the named object, otherwise an exception will be raised. [4]
>
> Similarly, classes are pickled by named reference, so the same restrictions in the unpickling environment apply. Note that **none of the class’s code or data is pickled**

If you want to send your friend the class and instances, send the class through a code defining the class `wow`, and the instances through the pickle file.

Comment: OK that seems to be cut and dry, thanks! I'm still not comfortable with the comment I made on the answer from @LaPriWa  "Section 11.1.4 "The following types can be pickled: ... classes that are defined at the top level of a module" which seems to me to say I should be able to do this" but I guess  taken together - you can pickle the class but you won't get what you want back.

Comment: You're welcome. As for that line, yeah, it seems to be confusing, I guess you can pickle the class to serialize any runtime changes to the class variables to be retrieved later, for example. EDIT: sorry, I just remember that the class data is also not pickled. Not sure what we could gain by pickling a class, then

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can pickle any object if you can pickle every attribute of that object. **Classes, functions, and methods cannot be pickled**.

Source: https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle

Don't destroy the class or import it as a module.

Comment: That's a definitive answer, but I'm trying to see how that meshes with bullet #7 in [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) documentation. Section 11.1.4 "The following types can be pickled: ... classes that are defined at the top level of a module" which seems to me to say I should be able to do this.

Comment: I guess it should say "you can pickle your Class but you can't get your class from a pickle."

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about security, both `dill` and `pickle` have the same issues.  However, if you want ease of use, `dill` handles the exact case you are looking to handle.  You can dynamically create a class and then save it's instance with `dill`… then pass the instance to an environment that doesn't have the class definition, and `dill` will still be able to recreate the class and the class instance.  This is because, unlike `pickle`, `dill` stores the class definition in the pickle (by default) as well as the class instance's state.

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...   x = 1
...   def bar(self, y):
...     return self.x + y
...   def __init__(self, z):
...     self.z = z
... 
>>> f = Foo(2)
>>> import dill
>>> with open('instance.pkl', 'w') as pkl: 
...   dill.dump(f, pkl)
... 
>>>
```

Then ship the file to another computer… restart a session, and like magic, it works.

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Sep  2 2015, 17:36:25) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dill
>>> with open('instance.pkl', 'r') as pkl:
...   f = dill.load(pkl)
... 
>>> f
<__main__.Foo object at 0x10eb4a450>
>>> f.x
1
>>> f.z
2
>>> print dill.source.getsource(f.__class__)
class Foo(object):
  x = 1
  def bar(self, y):
    return self.x + y
  def __init__(self, z):
    self.z = z

>>>
```

In short, I disagree with all of the other answers. You've even linked an answer in your question that shows that class instances, class instance state, and class code **can** be pickled. [Pickle python class instance plus definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726183/pickle-python-class-instance-plus-definition/28095208#28095208)

Comment: If you want to do the same thing using `pickle` and not `dill`, then you can.  All you have to do is use `copyreg` to register how to serialize the class by saving the code.  This is what `dill` does on top of `pickle`, so you can also do it by registering a definition that serializes a class.

Comment: Thanks. The question is truly about pickle; pickle being that module which is imported when I type `import pickle`.

Answer (score -1):

you must open pickle file in  binary mode as it mentioned [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle):

```
with open('data.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(data, f)
```

Comment: For the objects, it works fine as written `...'w')`. For the class, `...'wb')` and `...'rb')` do not change the error message `'module' object has no attribute 'wow'`.