# Do Pickle and Dill have similar levels of risk of containing malicious script?

Tags: python, pickle

Dill is obviously a very useful module, and it seems as long as you manage the files carefully it is relatively safe. But I was put off by the statement:

> Thus dill is not intended to be secure against erroneously or maliciously constructed data. It is left to the user to decide whether the data they unpickle is from a trustworthy source.

I read in in https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill. It's left to the user to decide how to manage their files.

If I understand correctly, once it has been pickled by dill, you can not *easily* find out what the original script will do without some special skill.

MY QUESTION IS: although I don't see a warning, **does a similar situation also exist for pickle?**

Comment: I'm the `dill` author.  you don't need special skills.  You can always inspect the pickle byte code instructions with `pickleutils.dis`.  That will tell you what's in the code.  It's not going to completely protect you, but you can see if there's some unexpected easter egg inside your object if there are unexpected instructions.  But, yes, only unpickle from trusted sources.

Comment: OK, well reading byte code is a *teeny bit* special, but doing it is probably a good exercise anyway. Thanks for the clarification, that's very helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dill is built on top of pickle, and the warnings apply just as much to pickle as they do to dill.

Pickle uses a *stack language* to effectively execute arbitrary Python code. An attacker can sneak in instructions to open up a backport to your machine, for example. Don't ever use pickled data from untrusted sources.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) includes an explicit warning:

> **Warning**: The `pickle` module is not secure against erroneous or maliciously constructed data. Never unpickle data received from an untrusted or unauthenticated source.

Comment: I see. So it could contain python with unintended consequences, python with malicious intent, or malicious instructions added after the pickling?

Comment: @uhoh: Exactly. Don't ever unpickle data that could have been tampered with.

Comment: There are three good answers here - I'm accepting this one on conciseness but **I recommend the reader to read the other answers also.**

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**

Because Pickle allows you to override the object serialization and deserialization, via

```
object.__getstate__()
```

> Classes can further influence how their instances are pickled; if the
>   class defines the method `__getstate__()`, it is called and the returned
>   object is pickled as the contents for the instance, instead of the
>   contents of the instance’s dictionary. If the `__getstate__()` method is
>   absent, the instance’s `__dict__` is pickled as usual.

```
object.__setstate__(state)
```

> Upon unpickling, if the class defines `__setstate__()`, it is called
>   with the unpickled state. In that case, there is no requirement for
>   the state object to be a dictionary. Otherwise, the pickled state must
>   be a dictionary and its items are assigned to the new instance’s
>   dictionary.

Because these functions can execute arbitrary code at the user's permission level, it is relatively easy to write a malicious deserializer -- e.g. one that deletes all the files on your hard disk.

Comment: Thanks @gbronner, this is helpful! I can see where to start reading now to dig further into serialization - something I was blissfully ignorant of yesterday!

Comment: The `__setstate__` method isn't actually pickled, only the data that'll be passed to it and a *string* reference on how to load that method. You don't need those methods at all to produce a malicious pickle, see https://www.cs.uic.edu/~s/musings/pickle.html for examples.

Comment: But to summarise, that blog post uses the `marshall` module to load fully-formed code objects (functions) from a pickle. It is the ability to re-purpose *any existing Python module* that makes pickle so powerful, not necessarily the ability for classes to influence how they are pickled and restored.

Answer (score 1):

> Although I don't see a warning, does a similar situation also exist for pickle?

Always, **always** assume that just because someone doesn't state it's dangerous it is **not** safe to use something.

That being said, [Pickle docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) do say the same:

> **Warning** The `pickle` module is not secure against erroneous or maliciously constructed data. Never unpickle data received from an untrusted or unauthenticated source.

So yes, that security risk exists on pickle, too.

To explain the background: pickle and dill restore the state of python objects. In CPython, the default python implementation, this means restoring `PyObjects` structs, which contain a length field. Modification of that, as an example, leads to funky effects and might have arbitrary effects on your python process' memory.

By the way, even assuming that data is not malicious doesn't mean you can un-pickle or un-dill just about anything that comes e.g. from a different python version. So, to me, that question is a bit of theoretical one: If you need portable objects, you will have to implement a rock-solid serialization/deserialization mechanism that transports the data you need transported, and nothing more or less.

Comment: Yes indeed it is right there at the top highlighted, and I must have scrolled right past it more than once, on my way to the following subsections. So are more, potentially dangerous  things possible, like os operations intended as file cleanup also having unintended consequences?

Comment: arbitrary code execution, which means *arbitrary* code execution within your executing user's privileges.

Comment: I see, yikes! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

#### This goes double for AI/LLM generated script!

From Ars Technical's March 2, 2024 [IN A PICKLE —Hugging Face, the GitHub of AI, hosted code that backdoored user devices Malicious submissions have been a fact of life for code repositories. AI is no different.](https://arstechnica.com/security/2024/03/hugging-face-the-github-of-ai-hosted-code-that-backdoored-user-devices/)

> How baller432 did it
>
> Like the other nine truly malicious models, the one discussed here used pickle, a format that has long been recognized as inherently risky. Pickles is commonly used in Python to convert objects and classes in human-readable code into a byte stream so that it can be saved to disk or shared over a network. This process, known as serialization, presents hackers with the opportunity of sneaking malicious code into the flow.
>
> The model that spawned the reverse shell, submitted by a party with the username baller432, was able to evade Hugging Face’s malware scanner by using pickle’s "**reduce**" method to execute arbitrary code after loading the model file.
>
> JFrog’s Cohen explained the process in much more technically detailed language:
>
> > In loading PyTorch models with transformers, a common approach involves utilizing the torch.load() function, which deserializes the model from a file. Particularly when dealing with PyTorch models trained with Hugging Face’s Transformers library, this method is often employed to load the model along with its architecture, weights, and any associated configurations. Transformers provide a comprehensive framework for natural language processing tasks, facilitating the creation and deployment of sophisticated models. In the context of the repository “baller423/goober2,” it appears that the malicious payload was injected into the PyTorch model file using the **reduce** method of the pickle module. This method, as demonstrated in the provided reference, enables attackers to insert arbitrary Python code into the deserialization process, potentially leading to malicious behavior when the model is loaded.
>
> Hugging Face has since removed the model and the others flagged by JFrog.

There is also a code example and more detailed explanation within the link. This will be an ongoing issue with a constantly changing risk landscape so a complete answer about this will be incomplete tomorrow.