# How to use dict() from one file to another python file

Tags: python

I have two python files in same folder `file1.py` `file2.py`.

`file1.py`

```
data = dict()

data["user1"] = "xyz"
data["user2"] = "abc"

#saving it in json
with open(myfile, "w") as f:    #myfile is a path to a json file
    json.dump(data , f, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

I want to use `data` in file2:

```
data["user3"] = "qwe"
data["user4"] = "rty"
```

and then use the values of `user3` & `user4` from file2 to save in `myfile`. I tried importing it but it didnt work. How can I resolve it.?

Thanks

Comment: "I tried importing it but it didnt work ..." How so? Please give a [mcve]. You are just telling us that some unknown code isn't working in some unspecified way. Not enough to go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this:**

In your file2:

```
from file1 import data

data['user3'] = "qwe"
data['user4'] = "rty"
```

Hope it will help you!

Answer (score 0):

Do this, In this file2.py:-

```
from file1 import data
```

Then you can perform any operation on data dictionary from file2.py

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pickle` (check [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)) for object serialization:

```
import pickle
a = dict()
a['hello'] = 'world'
pickle.dump(a, open('data.pkl', 'wb'))
```

and then import in other file:

```
import pickle
new_dict = pickle.load(open('data.pkl', 'rb'))
new_dict['hello']

>>> 'world'
```

And it works for any object :D

Comment: Use pickle responsibly. See [Do Pickle and Dill have similar levels of risk of containing malicious script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34314289/3904031)