# Safer or more pythonic way to save python kwargs back to yaml?

Tags: python, yaml

This is a heavily abstracted example where I build objects from variables stored in a .yaml file. I'm writing the reverse method to save them back as a new .yaml

I may create further objects via script, so the output yaml will in general be different.

I'm using `.locals()` to build a dictionary from the kwargs, and then `.pop()` to strip the ones I will not want to save.

This seems to work and do what I want, but I feel it is ugly. Am I missing a better, safer, or more pythonic way to do this?

I understand there is pickle and dill, but for the current question I'd like to restrict this to reading and writing yamls. ([because](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34314289/3904031))

**note:** if attributes are added later I don't want them saved. This is why I create ob.L right after instantiation.

Input .yaml:

```
bob:
  args: {'x':1, 'y':2}
sue:
  args: {'x':3, 'y':4}
```

Output .yaml:

```
bob:
  args:
    x: 1
    y: 2
new:
  args:
    x: 5
    y: 6
sue:
  args:
    x: 3
    y: 4
```

Current script:

```
class A(object):
    wow = 77
    def __init__(self, name, x, y):
        self.name = name
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.L = locals()
        self.L.pop('name')
        self.L.pop('self')

import yaml

with open('thing.yaml', 'r') as infile:
    d = yaml.load(infile)

obs = []
for name, info in d.items():
    ob = A(name, **info['args'])
    obs.append(ob)

newob = A('new', 5, 6)
obs.append(newob)

newob.ignore_me = 777   # this should not be saved

# rebuild the yaml
d = dict()
for ob in obs:
    info = dict()

    info['args'] = ob.L

    d[ob.name] = info

with open('newthing.yaml', 'w') as outfile:
    yaml.dump(d, outfile, default_flow_style=False, allow_unicode=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't understand why you're doing any of this. All you need to do is to load the YAML, add your new items, and then dump it again.

```
with open('thing.yaml', 'r') as infile:
    d = yaml.load(infile)
d['new'] = {'x': 5, 'y': 6}
with open('newthing.yaml', 'w') as outfile:
    yaml.dump(d, outfile, default_flow_style=False, allow_unicode=True)
```

Comment: This is an abstracted example of something much longer. Objects may be added in several ways, and what your suggesting may end up getting complicated.

Comment: The `.L` attribute "freezes" or preserves the instantiation information within the object, the two `.pop()`s get rid of the only two freeloaders that shouldn't be preserved. This way the objects can "re-yaml" themselves and I don't need to maintain and keep track of the dictionary `d`.

Comment: There could be instances added or subtracted from the `obs` list, or the list could be split into several lists. In the end, I'd like to send the instantiation variables of whichever objects exist in a given list back to a yaml, rather than to try to maintain dictionaries that describe what's in each list, each time a list is altered. Like I say, it may be ugly, but it does what I need it to do.

Comment: I'd like to ask an expanded version of this in code review instead. To avoid the appearance of cross-posting, I'd like to delete this question. Since the parallel dictionary approach isn't going to work for me, could I ask you to delete this answer so that I can delete the question? Thanks!

Comment: @uhoh Why don't you incorporate this answer into your existing code and post the modified code on Code Review instead?

Comment: Regardless of what you're planning, abstracted examples are unwelcome on Code Review. If you have any questions, find me in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor).

Comment: @Mast This answer is not at all what I want to do. I would of course write a different looking post in code review.

Comment: @uhoh Just make sure you post the real deal there to avoid the same situation happening twice. That would be unfortunate and a lot of effort wasted by all parties involved. Might want to check [the guide](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777/52915) just to be sure.

Comment: @Mast I understand. I think "I can't understand why you're doing any of this." should have bee a comment, *not posted as an answer*. If you think about it, that's what comments are for.